# Finding distance between elements of two different list

Tags: python, scipy, euclidean-distance

The code below finds the Euclidean distance between each element of list a and each element of list b.

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
b = [[10, 20]]

Final_distance = []
for i in [j for sub in a for j in sub]:
    for k in [m for t in b for m in t]:
        dist = distance.euclidean(i, k)
        Final_distance.append(dist)
print(Final_distance)
```

The output is

```
[9.0, 19.0, 8.0, 18.0, 7.0, 17.0, 6.0, 16.0, 5.0, 15.0, 4.0, 14.0]
```

But for very large list it is taking very long time. Is there a way to reduce the time complexity of the above code?

Answer (score 3):

Since your euclidian distances are on scalars, it's equivalent to the absolute value between each point. So you can repeat your arrays in the appropriate order using `np.repeat` and `np.tile`, and just subtract your arrays from one another:

```
import numpy as np

a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
b = [[10, 20]]

a1 = np.array(a).flatten()
b1 = np.array(b).flatten()

Final_distance = np.abs(np.subtract(np.repeat(a1, len(b1)), np.tile(b1, len(a1))))
```

Which returns:

```
array([ 9, 19,  8, 18,  7, 17,  6, 16,  5, 15,  4, 14])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is very faster than my approach. But for very large a and b i.e. if a contains 10000 lists and b contains 2000 lists, then this approach might brings problem with memory resulting in memory error.